# Reporting duplicate entry for a given set of data

Tags: java, performance, comparative-review

While solving a problem on an online judge, I tried with these two implementations.

These two implementations do the same thing. Task is to report duplicate entry for a given set of data.

Implementation #1 : Converts input data to a `String` and adds to a `HashSet`. After all the input is read, appropriate message is displayed.

```
class Databse2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());//number of test cases
        int N=0,R=0,C=1;
        while(t-->0){ //while there are more test cases
            HashSet<String> set=new HashSet<String>();
            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                N=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                R=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());//Number of Rows of data
            }

            int ID=0,SC=0;boolean haha=true;
            for(int i=0;i<R;i++){ //for number of rows read each record in the row
                st=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                    ID=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    SC=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                }
                String key=ID+""+SC;//convert to string,this combo is used to check for duplicates
                haha=haha && set.add(key);


            }
            if(haha)
                System.out.println("Scenario #"+C+": possible");
            else System.out.println("Scenario #"+C+": impossible");
            C++;
        }
    }
}
```

`Running time = 3.41 sec (for N number of test cases)`

Implementation #2: Same task is accomplished as in Implementation #1 but in a different way. An object is created based on input type and added to `HashSet`.

```
class Database {

private int ID;
private int SC;

public Database(int ID,int SC){
    this.ID=ID;
    this.SC=SC;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (obj instanceof Database) ? ID==((Database)obj).ID:SC==((Database)obj).SC;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 31*(ID+SC);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int N=0,R=0,C=1;
    while(t-->0){
        HashSet<Database> set=new HashSet<Database>();
        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            N=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            R=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }
        int ID=0,SC=0;boolean haha=true;
        for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
            st=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                ID=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                SC=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            }
            haha=haha?set.add(new Database(ID, SC)):false;
        }
        String str=haha?"Scenario #"+C+": possible":"Scenario #"+C+": impossible";
        System.out.println(str);
        C++;
    }
}
}
```

`Running Time #2 = 2.74 sec (for N number of test cases)`

What causes implementation #2 to be faster? Is it the `hashCode` method?

Comment: I'd say it's the string concatenation in version 1. Not sure though. You may want to give a try at caliper for being sure.

Comment: Did you do multiple runs of each? If not, i would do that then compare the mean times to each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `String.equals()` compare their `char[]` inside, which is slower than simply compare two `int`s.
2. `String` concatenation is slower than creating a `Database`.
3. `String.hashcode()` is just like its `equals`.

Note that your implementation of `Database.equals` is incorrect, though you're lucky this time.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (obj instanceof Database) && ID == ((Database)obj).ID &&
            SC == ((Database)obj).SC;
}
```

The `hashcode` implementation is only a suggestion.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 31 * (31 * 17 + ID) + SC;
}
```

Comment: `String.hashCode()` uses a precalculated `hashCode` so this is not any slower that comparing integers.

Comment: @UwePlonus But it still calculate it once, and because `hashcode` cache the result, I put it at the third cause.

Comment: @johnchen902 thanks for pointing out incorrect `equals` implementation.